# Reading parameter and then finding single element in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a service `carriersService` with method `getAll()`, which returns an `Observable<Carrier[]>`.
In my component, I'm trying to read route parameter `carrierId`, find the carrier with such `carrierId` and assign it to a local variable

```
let carrier = null;

this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap(
        (params: ParamMap) => this.carriersService.getAll()));
```

I need to find a single Carrier from an Observable of `Carrier[]` using `params.get('carrierId')` and assign it to local carrier variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

combineLatest will emit once both observables have emitted, this allows you to use the route param to find the carrier in the array.

```
combineLatest(
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(p => p.get('carrierId'))),
  this.carriersService.getAll()
).pipe(
  map(([carrierId, carriers]) => carriers.find(carrier => carrier.id === carrierId))
).subscribe(carrier => {
  this.carrier = carrier;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. What I found is combineLatest in this form is deprecated. New version takes an array of observables as an argument. Like this: 
```combineLatest([this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(p => p.get('carrierId'))),
  this.carriersService.getAll()]).pipe(
  map(([carrierId, carriers]) => carriers.find(carrier => carrier.id === carrierId))
).subscribe(carrier => {
  this.carrier = carrier;
});```